# Is it possible to separate normalized device coordinates and window clipping in openGL (glViewport)

Tags: opengl, 2d, clipping

Is there a way to set a transformation for NDC to window, but separately specify the clipping region so it matches the actual window size?

Background: I have a bunch of openGL code that renders a 2D map to a window. It's a lot of complex code, because I use both the GPU and the CPU to draw on the map, so it's important that I keep to a consistent coordinate system in both places. To keep that simple, I use glViewport(0,0,mapSizeX, mapSizeY), and now map coordinates correspond well to pixel coordinates in the frame buffer, exactly what I need. I can use GLSL to draw some of the map, call glReadPixels and use the CPU to draw on top of that, and glDrawPixels to send that back to the frame buffer, all of that using the same coordinate system. Finally I use GLSL to draw a few final things over that (that I don't want zoomed). That all works, except...

The window isn't the same size as the map, and glViewport doesn't just set up the transformation. It also sets up clipping. So now when I go to draw a few last items, and the window is larger than the map, things I draw near the top of the screen get clipped away. Is there a workaround?

Comment: *"I set the normalized device coordinates to the size of the map"* - No. Normalized device space is a unique cube with the left, bottom, near (-1, -1, -1) and the right, top, far (1, 1, 1). You cannot set or change it. Clipping is done in clip space (`gl_Position`): -w <=  x, y, z  <= w

Comment: I clarified my use of glViewport, in case I was unclear. Are you saying there is no way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

> glViewport doesn't just set up the transformation. It also sets up clipping.

No, it *just* sets up the transformation. By the time the NDC-to-window space transform happens, clipping has *already been done*. That happened [immediately after vertex processing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Clipping); your vertex shader (or whatever you're doing to transform vertices) handled that based on how it transformed vertices into clip-space.

You should use the viewport to set up how you want the NDC box to visibly appear in the window. Your VS needs to handle the transformation into the clipping area. So it effectively decides how much of the world gets put into the NDC box that things get clipped to.

Basically, you have map space (the coordinates used by your map) and clip-space (the coordinates after vertex transformations). And you have some notion of which part of the map you want to actually draw to the window. You need to transform the region of your map that you want to see such that the corners of this region appear in the corners of the clipping box (for orthographic projections, this is typically [-1, 1]).

In compatibility OpenGL, this might be defined by using `glOrtho` for othographic projections to transform from you. In a proper vertex shader, you'll need to provide an appropriate orthographic matrix.